# How to add "route action" into response content with Ajax Zend2?

Tags: ajax, json, zend-framework2

I am new to zend framework and trying to test my first app about  ajax with zend2.
I want to show a link when I return a response from my controller ! I try anyways but cann't view !

I try this:

Here my HTML:

```
<select id="my_list" onChange="showlist(this.value);" name="my_list">
     <option value="1">A</option>
     <option value="2">B</option>
     <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Here my Ajax Script:

```
function showlist(id){
    $.post("user/list", {
       content: id
    },function(data){
        if(data.response == true){
            $('#div_show').html(data['html']);
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

And my controller:

```
public function listAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $post_data = $request->getPost();
        $id = $post_data['content'];
        if($id){
         /* $html = $group;  It's Ok ! I can view group value !*/
            $html = '<a href="'.$this->url('user',array('action'=>'view','id'=>$group)).'">Test !</a>';
            $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => true,'html'=>$html)));
        }
        else{
           $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => false)));
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

I can view group value when I select `listbox`, but I cann't see the link when I want to view its detail !

It's my first question ! Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = '<?php echo $this->url('user', array('action' => 'list')); ?>';
function showlist(id){
$.post(url, {
   content: id
},function(data){
    if(data.response == true){
        $('#div_show').html(data['html']);
    }
}, 'json');
}
```